# Str.split elements don't exist when used in function using row

Tags: python, pandas

df5

```
award_id_fain    award_id_uri    loan_no
1234                             1234
                 12345678:4      12345678
```

I'm using a function to capture the parts of a string that come before a character. I have a df with a column "award_id_uri" of target values.Given 12345678:4, I want the output to be 12345678. I think I have the syntax down but I'm getting a

```
"'str' object has no attribute 'str'"
```

error message.

My current approach is to declare a function then apply it. The function and call are below.

```
def loan_cap(row):
    if pd.notnull(row['award_id_fain']):
        loan_no = row['award_id_fain']
    else: loan_no = row['award_id_uri'].str.split(':').str[0]
    return loan_no


df5['loan_no'] = df5.apply(loan_cap, axis = 1)
```

I think the fault lies in the str[0] part of the function. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you just need `loan_no = row['award_id_uri'].str.split(':')[0]`

Comment: Tried that Buckeye; same error message

Comment: Oh I see. when you do `row['award_id_uri']` you are getting an element. Not a series

Comment: `series.str.split()` is meant to be applied to an entire series at once, not row-by-row. Otherwise you're operating on individual strings, which have a `.split()` method, but not a `.str.split()` method. It would help to see some sample input and output to understand your problem better

Comment: `row['award_id_uri']` is already a string, you only need `row['award_id_uri'].split(':')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this instead.

```py
def loan_cap(row):
    if row['award_id_fain']:
        return row['award_id_fain']
    else: 
        return row['award_id_uri'].split(':')[0]

df5['loan_no'] = df5.apply(loan_cap, axis = 1)
```

As mentioned by other comments, row["award_id_uri"] will return a value, in your case its a string, so you can apply directly your split function on it.

#### Note

Add a try/except block if row['award_id_uri'] do not contain ":".

Comment: @wolf7687 a pleasure, you can mark this awserd as approved by cliking on the marked sign below the up/dow vote button.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `apply` if possible, try to think in term of the whole series, not row by row. In this case, you can use `fillna()`:

```
df['loan_no'] = df.award_id_fain.fillna(df.award_id_uri.str.split(':', expand=True)[0])
```

Output:

```
   award_id_fain award_id_uri   loan_no
0         1234.0          NaN      1234
1            NaN   12345678:4  12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `.str` part here. It says it already knows, that it's `str`.

Try:

```py
def loan_cap(row):
    if pd.notnull(row['award_id_fain']):
        loan_no = row['award_id_fain']
    else: loan_no = row['award_id_uri'].split(':').str[0]
    return loan_no
```

Answer (score 0):

try:
`row['award_id_uri'].split(':')[0]`

`row['award_id_uri']`  evaluates to a string which you are calling `.str` on so you get the error.

To illustrate try :
`"this is a string".split(" ")` 
and 
`"this is a string".str.split(" ")`